# TypeError: NoneType, when trying to loop crop images

Tags: python

```
from os import listdir
import cv2


files=listdir('/home/raymond/Desktop/Test/Test') #Importing the dir for cropping
for file in files:
    img = cv2.imread('/home/raymond/Desktop/Test/Test'+file) # reading a single image from the dir
    crop_img = img[0:1600, 0:1600]
    cv2.imwrite('/home/raymond/Desktop/Test/cropped'+file,crop_img) # write new data to img
```

Im trying to loop crop images, while getting an error of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Files.py", line 8, in <module>
    crop_img = img[0:1600, 0:1600]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
(fixi) ➜  exercises
```

Comment: Put `'/home/raymond/Desktop/Test/Test'+file` in a variable, and see what it's outputting. Does that file exist?

Comment: Thank you, I was missing a '/'

Comment: exercises python3 Files.py
/home/raymond/Desktop/Test/Test20180711072148_180629035603030269807083_1_IO.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Files.py", line 10, in <module>
    crop_img = img[0:1600, 0:1600]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `NoneType` is the type of the Python object `None`, which indicates there is no real value. The error means that `img` is `None` (since it's the only thing you're trying to subscript, or use `[]` on, in the quoted line). Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html) for `imread` doesn't seem to indicate when it returns `None`, so check for common issues like if the file exists. In this case, you're probably missing a `/` in the path; try [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing a slash at the end of the path here:

```
img = cv2.imread('/home/raymond/Desktop/Test/Test'+file) # reading a single image from the dir
```

Should be:

```
img = cv2.imread('/home/raymond/Desktop/Test/Test/'+file) # reading a single image from the dir
```

or even better:

```
import os 
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join('/home/raymond/Desktop/Test/Test/',file)) # reading a single image from the dir
```

Answer (score 0):

> img = cv2.imread('/home/raymond/Desktop/Test/Test'+file)

Hello Dan Raymond,

This cannot work because **Python** does not add a slash (/) before listed filenames.
Which means that if you have a filename "hello", then what is appended to '/home/raymond/Desktop/Test/Test' is "hello" which results in **'/home/raymond/Desktop/Test/Testhello'** which does not exist.

Replace your line with this:

```py
img = cv2.imread('/home/raymond/Desktop/Test/Test/'+file)
```